# Replace string subrange with character and maintain length in Swift

Tags: swift, string, replace

I would like to hide sensitive user data in strings by replacing a certain subrange with asterisks. For instance, replace all characters except the first and last three, turning

"sensitive info"

into

"sen********nfo".

I have tried this:

```
func hideInfo(sensitiveInfo: String) -> String {
  let fIndex = sensitiveInfo.index(sensitiveInfo.endIndex, offsetBy: -4)
  let sIndex = sensitiveInfo.index(sensitiveInfo.startIndex, offsetBy: 3)
  var hiddenInfo = sensitiveInfo
  let hiddenSubstring = String(repeating: "*", count: hiddenInfo.count - 6)
  hiddenInfo.replaceSubrange(sIndex...fIndex, with: hiddenSubstring)
  return hiddenInfo
}
```

and it works. But it seems overcomplicated. Is there a simpler and/or more elegant way of achieving this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about building the string with the first three characters (`prefix(3)`) the created asterisk substring and the last three characters (`suffix(3)`)

```
func hideInfo(sensitiveInfo: String) -> String {
    let length = sensitiveInfo.utf8.count
    if length <= 6 { return sensitiveInfo }
    return  String(sensitiveInfo.prefix(3) + String(repeating: "*", count: length - 6) + sensitiveInfo.suffix(3))
}
```

Comment: Yep, much better. Thank you!

Comment: Why use sensitiveInfo.utf8.count and not sensitiveInfo.count?